# Dos batch file to find a specific value in first 6 columns

Tags: batch-file, find, dos

I have to create a dos batch file that will look at a text file and check if the word ERRORS is in columns

```
123456
ERRORS
```

The word appears in other parts of the text file but those are not an issue.

This is what I have so far

```
Find "ERRORS" c:\temp\*.txt >> c:\temp\check_errors.txt
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Findstr /r ".......ERRORS" c:\temp\*.txt >> c:\temp\check_errors.txt
```

should do the trick - seven dots (each one represents one character-position) since you have six digits and a space before the string "ERRORS".

Comment: I was able to get it working doing it like this.  Findstr /B "ERRORS:" c:\temp\*.txt >> c:\temp\check_errors.txt.  I needed the word errors to be at the beginning of the line.  Thank you

Comment: Great! - Please click the tick to show that the problem has been solved.